# Create an AppLink for existing Content that works in the Facebook App

Tags: android, facebook, applinks

I have existing content ( e.g. https://3doo.com/web/medium/details?mediaId=41c087be-2f4a-4ee6-8336-2d56a702fba8 )

For this content I have created meta tags according to the facebook metadata reference and AppLink documentation.

The AppLink works fine when opened on:

- PC Browser
- Android Browser

It does not work when opened in the Android Facebook app. A short notice pops up that says "There was a problem opening the app." and nothing else.

How Do I get my AppLink to work with the Android FB App?

Answer (score 0):

To properly configure your Android Links to deeplink from Facebook, you need to [properly configure Facebook App Links](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android/).

The easier option is to use a third-party like [Branch's Android SDK](http://branch.io) that handles Facebook deep linking as well as linking from all of platforms in one packaged link.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but the App Links and how my App handles them works fine. The problem was how the facebook app handles the meta tags for the app links.

Answer (score 0):

So according to the [metadata reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/metadata-reference) of facebook the "al:android:package" tag was optional, without explaining what about it is optional.

It is optional if you don't care about opening your app via deeplink from the facebook app. If the facebook app on Android should be able to start your Android App you have to provide the fully qualified classname of the activity to which the facebook app should redirect.